# I am having trouble wrapping text within a View within a View. How do I keep it from running off the screen?

Tags: text, storyboard, overflow

I have an existing app on the AppStore that was largely hand-coded, every year, I spend time updating it, to make sure it works with the new iOS device sizes. I'm trying to update it to be more easily adjusted, when Apple changes screen sizes and resolutions. But I'm having trouble with using text overflow within a View within a View. So as to make the text not editable, I inserted it as a Label, for lack of finding a better way.

I have a main View and three sections within the main View. The top section is a one line title, at the top of the screen. The second section is a View, of a different color, that contains the problem text and is supposed to use up all the space to the bottom button. The third section is a button at the bottom of the screen.

I'm having two problems with this. First, text runs off the right side of the screen, in a single line, when in the Main Storyboard, instead of wrapping and expanding down the screen. Second, the blue View and the text it contains, within the main View, does not appear at all, when I run the app in the simulator.

I'm including two images that show the problem and what I'm trying to achieve.
[What I see in the Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lQdc.jpg)
[What I'm trying to achieve both in the Storyboard and in the running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOFUO.jpg)

I've played around with many constraint variations. I also deleted all constraints and started over several times.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed us your constraints -- but, here is an example of how to setup your labels, "purple view" and button...

Quick note: it can be very helpful - particularly when getting started - to give your UI elements contrasting background colors... makes it much easier to see what's going on with the framing.

Examine the constraints used here:

[image]

In addition to those constraints, we need to tell auto-layout that *only the description label* should stretch/compress vertically.

So, for `Title Label` and `Desc And Sub Title Label` and `Continue` button, set Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance priorities to Required (1000):

[image]

Now, with a few different length descriptions, we get this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice, though, that if the text is too long it will be clipped:

[image]

So, you might want to put the description label in a scroll view:

[image]

and, instead of clipping (...) the end of the text, we can scroll when the text is too long:

[image]

[image]

[image]